# Error in plotting a C5.0 decision tree in R

Tags: r, plot, decision-tree

I'm trying to plot my decision tree model.

```
cnt_c50 <- C5.0Control(CF=0.25,minCases=30,sample=0.7)
myTree <- C5.0(Y ~ X1+X2+X3+....+X30, data=data, control= cnt_c50,trials=100)
summary(myTree)
```

When I run `summary(myTree)` there is no warning, no error, everything is fine.

But when I want to visualize it : `plot(myTree)` , I have this error message :

> Error in partysplit(varid = as.integer(i), index = index, info = k,
>   prob = NULL) :    minimum of ‘index’ is not equal to 1 In addition:
>   Warning message: In min(index, na.rm = TRUE) :   no non-missing
>   arguments to min; returning Inf

I tried to define which tree I want to visualize with `plot(myTree,trial=9)`, and it returns this message :

> Error in !all.equal(diff(sort(unique(index))), rep(1, max(index, na.rm
>   = TRUE) - : invalid argument type

When I try with `trials=1` instead of `trials=100`, I have this message :

> Error in if (!n.cat[i]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I also tried this because I saw it in a response on this website but it seems to be for CART Trees :

```
library(rattle)
fancyRpartplot(myTree)
```

and I have this error :

> Error in if (model$method == "class") { : argument is of length zero

I read that it could be due to a lack of values in a category (for example a category with only 1 or 2 people) so I ran without some variables with small categories but it was the same.

I also tried this function http://r-project-thanos.blogspot.fr/2014/09/plot-c50-decision-trees-in-r.html but I am not a good programmer and I had errors too...

Did anyone have the same problem and can help me ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This happens when you try to plot an object that was not produced with rpart()

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Have you an idea about how to plot a C5.0 plot ?